# rSpec - how to test select inside a model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a model with a method that returns just the first name of a user and a qty.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.list
    select("firstname, qty").order("qty desc").all
  end
end
```

how would I test the return value with rSpec?

```
User.list.should == [?????]
```

The method returns an array of User objects, but with only two attributes.  This is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `.list` returns incomplete Users, your best bet may be to pull out their attributes as a Hash:

```
User.list.map { |u| u.attributes }.
    should == [{ :firstname => "John", :qty => 10 }, { ... }]
```

Answer (score 1):

`factory_girl` will DRY this right up:

```
fewer_qty_user = Factory.create(:blank_user, :qty => 100, :firstname => 'Bob')
more_qty_user  = Factory.create(:blank_user, :qty => 200, :firstname => 'Alice')
User.list.should == [more_qty_user, fewer_qty_user]
```

Comment: How does factory girl know to return incomplete objects? In other words, the full instances it creates won't compare equal to the instances returned by `select` will they?

Comment: Thats right.  I tried it like @Johns answer initially but they weren't equal.

Comment: They will if you define your Factory accordingly.

Comment: Care to expand on that? How might you define your factories? And how might you get `Factory.create` to return a partial instance with no id?